# RubyOnRails CSV Export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export

Long story short.  I'm new to RubyOnRails.  The rest of my development team has left the company and I'm the last one left.  I am taking over code that they all did.  How do I export the csv file to put all the data on multiple lines?  Right now, the code puts multiple records into one line in the csv file.

```
class CancelledDealCSVGenerator
  require 'csv'

  def self.generate_csv(deals)
     CSV.open("#{AppConfig.cancelled_csv_folder}/CANNED.CSV", "a") do |csv|
       deals.each do |deal|
        csv << [deal.customer_number, deal.deal_number, deal.contract_number, deal.cancel_date]
       end
     end
  end

end
```

This is how it SHOULD look

999999  AAA000  55555   6/23/2011 08:27

999998  AAA001  55554   6/23/2011 08:15

But this is how it DOES look

999999  AAA000  55555   6/23/2011 08:27 
999998  AAA001  55554   6/23/2011 08:15

Comment: I'm a little confused, could you please post a snippet of the CSV file it's currently generating and a snippet of a hypothetical CSV file you want it to generate?

Comment: What version of Ruby and Rails are you using and what OS is the app running on?

The code as you have written above should be printing a line per deal as expected. I've verified it on Ruby 1.9.2p136 + Rails 3.0.7.

Comment: @gcastro - That is what I thought.  I have looked all over the place and as far as I can tell the syntax is correct I don't know what I'm missing.  The OS is Ubuntu Server 10.10 with ruby 1.9.2p136 is where the csv is generated.  It then is being put into an AS/400 system.

Comment: What are you looking at the csv with? Does it understand unix line endings? What could be happening is that the file has unix line endings and you're looking at it with a windows program that expects dos-style line endings. If you're on Windows, try using Notepad++, wordpad, or a programmer's text editor (not notepad!) to view the file.

Comment: @Jeff Paquette - I'm sorry I should have specified that.  Looking at it in Windows like you said is fine, the problem lies in the AS/400.  For some reason when it imports into that system it does not see it as two separate records.  How do a specify different line endings?  If I could do that, maybe I can play with a few variations to see what works with the AS/400.

Comment: @ryan bartlett - I don't have any experience with AS/400 but a quick google turned up some rather frightening notes about ebcdic characters... you may need to convert the file after transferring it to the as/400, or use a transfer method that will do any conversion necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what CSV plugin/gem that you are using.  If it is a simple one that simple opens a file and writes to it, this should work.

```
class Deal
  def to_csv(delimiter=",")
    [deal.customer_number, deal.deal_number, deal.contract_number, deal.cancel_date].join(delimiter)
  end
end

class CancelledDealCSVGenerator
  require 'csv'

  def self.generate_csv(deals)
     CSV.open("#{AppConfig.cancelled_csv_folder}/CANNED.CSV", "a") do |csv|
       csv << deals.map(&:to_csv).join("\n")
     end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it looks like your problem is not really with the RoR code but with the fact that you're looking at the file on an EBCDIC system.

You'll need to convert the files from an ASCII encoding to EBCDIC (see [IBM ASCII TO EBCDIC conversion](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/features/unix/bpxa1p03.html#cmd))

Basically you're looking at:

```
iconv -f IS08859-1 -t IBM-1047 canned.csv > converted.csv
```